# Collect all the products of given categories

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

A `category` hasMany `products`. How can I collect the `products` of a couple of `categories`? This code doesn't work:

**controller.js**

```
selectedCategories: Ember.computed.filter('model.categories', function(model.categories, index) {
  return (index < 10);
}).property('model.categories'),

productsOfSelectedCategories: Ember.computed('selectedCategories', 'model.products', function() {
  var selectedCategories = this.get('selectedCategories');
  var products;

  productsOfSelectedCategories.map((category) => {
    products.push(category.products);
  })

  return products;
}),
```

**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      categories: this.store.find('category'),
      products: this.store.find('product'),
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Where did `productsOfSelectedCategories` come from?

Comment: Your model hook needs to return a promise or a model.  Store.find returns a promise, so essentially you are returning a hash of promises. Let's fix this part first by either using store.all or ember.RSVP.hash